# jQuery - Bind click to specific Ajax content element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events, click

I have this `form` that loads using `jQuery` `$.ajax` another `form` inside a container.

The list:

[image]

The loaded content within the container called `form_load_dropdown_content`:

[image]

On the left I have two small icons for edit and add. I want to use another `ajax` call to run specific `PHP` scripts to carry on the action desired.

I have the following problem:

- when I click on each icon `submit` and respectively `reset` buttons display
- when I click on the `reset` the both `submit` and `reset` are set to `display: none`
- when I click on any the icon again, the `click` remains `bind` to the previous icon clicked before.

This is what I am doing:

```
form_load_dropdown_content.on("click", ".icon", function() {
// reusable selectors
var icon_box = $(".box_edit_icons");
var button_box = $(".box_buttons");
var submit_btn  = $(".box_buttons input[type='submit']");
var reset_btn   = $(".box_buttons input[type='reset']");
var option_value_input = $("input.option_value");
var option_order_input = $("input.option_order");

// common functions
button_box.show();
icon_box.hide();

if($(this).hasClass("ico_edit_small"))
{
    // editing
    form_load_dropdown_content.on("click", "input[type='reset']", function(event){
        alert("reset from edit");
        button_box.hide();
        icon_box.show();
    });
}
else if($(this).hasClass("ico_add_small"))
{
    // adding
    form_load_dropdown_content.on("click", "input[type='reset']", function(event){
        alert("reset from add");
        button_box.hide();
        icon_box.show();
    });
}
```

How can I differentiate between the two clicks, so that when I display the `submit` and `reset` from a specific icon type to run differentiated actions?

More clear:

- when I click `icon_add_small` and then `reset` => output: 'reset from add'
- then when I click `icon_edit_small` and then `reset` => output: 'reset from edit'... and so on without mixing the clicks.

I truly appreciate any help. I tried everything regarding stopping the propagation of the click... but nothing worked.

**-----------------------------------------------------------**

Edit:

I changed the `if` part to the following code and it works. Should I expect any problems for unbinding the click?

```
if($(this).hasClass("ico_edit_small"))
{
    // editing
    reset_btn.off("click");
    reset_btn.click(function(event){
        alert("reset from edit");
        button_box.hide();
        icon_box.show();
    });
}
else if($(this).hasClass("ico_add_small"))
{
    // adding
    reset_btn.off("click");
    reset_btn.click(function(event){
        alert("reset from add");
        button_box.hide();
        icon_box.show();
    });
}
```